# How to supply 'supported datatypes' to DynamoDB during 'putItem' in Node on Express

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a Node-Express server setup on Elastic Beanstalk and I'm trying to get the '/signup' route to respond with a successful input into DynamoDB. How do I ensure that I've set the AttributeValues appropriately to 'supply supported datatypes'?

I have the datatypes set in the object `item` I create before supplying that object to `putItem` however this doesn't seem to solve my issue regarding 'AttributeValues.'

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    console.log('\nreq.body: ', req.body);
    var item = {
        'email': {'S': req.body.email},
        'name': {'S': req.body.name},
        'participating': {'BOOL': req.body.participating},
        'theme': {'S': req.body.theme}
    };

    ddb.putItem({
        'TableName': 'website-db',
        'Item': item,
        'Expected': { email: { Exists: false } }
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            var returnStatus = 500;
            // console.log(err);

            if (err.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
                returnStatus = 409;
            }

            console.log('DDB Error: ' + err);
            res.status(returnStatus).send(err);
        } else {
            sns.publish({
                'Message': 'Name: ' + req.body.name + "\r\nEmail: " + req.body.email
                                    + "\r\nParticipating: " + req.body.participating
                                    + "\r\nTheme: " + req.body.theme,
                'Subject': 'New Signup',
                'TopicArn': snsTopic
            }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).end();
                    console.log('SNS Error: ' + err);
                } else {
                    res.status(201).end();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I'm double-checking through the console that I'm not sending null values through to the DynamoDB method (other similar problems online were caused by null values to `putItem`), but the following error is returned:

```
message: "Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the 
supported datatypes",
code: "ValidationException",
time: "2019-01-07T05:37:29.911Z",
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 0
```

I'm sure my issue is just a missing parameter or something but there doesn't seem to be much information matching my issue specifically. Thanks in advance for the assistance. I'm pretty new to Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Make sure that there is no  null or empty values in your attributes (req.body.email, req.body.name & others). If there is a null or empty value in your attribute, avoid storing it. If you really want to store it use the following datatype for null values alone { NULL: true }. Incase of any issue faced share the console output of variable 'item'.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of returning 'item'. Seems obvious now, but I was logging the parsed response right before and assuming the values passed were fine (doesn't pay to assume too much, clearly). There's a weird variable I'm investigating now.